# iFrame validation http get SRC

Tags: angular, iframe, rxjs

As I have read before, I cannot validate if an iFrame is loaded, not loaded or still loading in Chrome using onError or onLoad functions, so I decided to test the URL provided as SRC for the iFrame using a simple http get.

I start loading the iFrame with an specific URL, and check the URL at the same time using http get. If the http get returns a 200 OK, it means the iFrame was loaded correctly so I hide an error message (this.iFrameStatus = false;). If the http returns an error, then I should change the iFrame URL and show the error message (this.iFrameStatus = true;).

Component

```
export class StatusComponent implements OnInit {
  public iFrameUrl: any;
  public iFrame: any;
  public iFrameStatus: boolean = false;
  public counter: number = 0;

  public errorMessage: any;
  //Assign URL to iFrame in constructor
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public _element: ElementRef, private _verificationService: VerificationService) {
    this.iFrameUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(constant.Url);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.iFrameStatusVerification();
    }, 3000);
  }

  //Verify if iFrame is correctly loaded
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.iFrame = this._element.nativeElement.querySelector('.iFrame');
  }

  iFrameStatusVerification() {
    this._verificationService.getAppStatus().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('success', data);
        this.iFrameStatus = false;
        this.iFrameUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(constant.Url);
      },
      error => {
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        console.log('error', error);
        console.log('error status', error.status);
        console.log('error ok', error.ok);

        this.iFrameStatus = true;
        //this.iFrame.src = constant.emptyIFrame;
        this.iFrameUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(constant.emptyIFrame);

      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class VerificationService {
  //External App iFrame Verification
  getAppStatus(): Observable<String[]> {
    let url = constant.localServer + constant.Url;
    console.log(url);
    return this.http.get(url, this._requestOptions)
      .timeout(5000)
      .map(res => { let body = res.json(); return body; })
      .catch((err: any): any => {
        this.handleError(err, 'Error app not found ');
        //return Observable.of(err);
      });
  }

  handleError(err: any, message: string) {
    let errMsg = (err.message) ? err.message :
      err.status ? `${err.status} - ${err.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.of(err);
   }
}
```

this._requestOptionsare is an injected service from which I get the header options for the Cross Origin properties.

The iFrame is loaded, I receive a 200 OK from the URL but then the error message is shown and the src is changed.

I try to print the error status or message in my component (console.log('error status', error.status);) but I always get an undefined. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at the end I couldn´t use HttpErrorResponse, but I dig deeper in my http get and it was an obvious error.

When a set the variable URL for an iFrame, it works and I get a 200 OK, on the other hand when I do an http get I have to specify in my header the type of data I want to accept. In this case is a document with HTML , so setting request options "Accept" : "text/html, ..." did the trick.

iFrame Verification

```
  getAppStatus(): Observable<String[]> {
    let url = constant.Url;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .timeout(2000)
       .catch(this.handleErrorMessage);
  }
```

The second error was using the map operator, normally you can use 
.map(this.extractData)

```
extractData(res:Response){
    let body = res.json();
    console.log('Body', body);
    return body || [];
}
```

which won´t work if you try to extract a json value from an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse)** to check possible failures from external API.

How to use it?

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


http
  .get<ItemsResponse>('api url')
  .subscribe(

     data => {...},

     (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {

        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);

      } else {

        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it, although I´m getting a "Cannot find the module" error. I guess I have to first install the package.

Comment: unfortunately I think I cannot use HttpErrorResponse because I need @angular/common 4.3 and I´m using the version 4.0.3, which is the only version I can use.